# How to remove the last character from all the data in a column using python?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have data like this in a column of a table.

```
RcHm_v2.0_CPg0501681
RcHm_v2.0_CPg0501691
RcHm_v2.0_CPg0501701
RcHm_v2.0_CPg0501711
RcHm_v2.0_CPg0501721
RcHm_v2.0_CPg0501731
```

I need to remove the last character from all these data.
I have this,

```py
for row in reader:
    transcript_id = row[1]
    gene_id = transcript_id.split(".")[0]
    row[1] = gene_id
    row[2] = gene_id
    row[16] = transcript_id
    writer.writerow(row)
```

From the 2nd line,

```py
    gene_id = transcript_id.split(".")[0]
```

it will remove all the things after the "."(dot).(Just consider the above line of code). I need to remove the last character. I'll be grateful if someone can help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about `gene_id = transcript_id[:-1]` , this is simple string slicing, read [this article](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) please.

Answer (score 1):

gene_id = gene_id[:-1]

This will return all but the last character and reassign it to the same variable

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to remove the last character, why are you using split?

`gene_id = transcript_id[0:len(transcript_id)-1]`

Here is a simple example

```
var1 = "Something.Else"
var2 = var2=var1[0:len(var1)-1]
print(var2)
Something.Els
```